# how do I upgrade my processor on my MacBook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro

I am trying to download a piece of equipment which requires at least a 1.8 Ghz processor. My MacBook Air has only 1.7 Ghz. Is it possible to upgrade it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! No, it is not possible to update pretty much any notebook processor without very advanced equipment / knowledge, and it is usually not done. MacBook Air are particularly not design for upgrades of any kind. Take a look at this question regarding a PC CPU upgrade: http://superuser.com/questions/142886/upgrading-laptop-processor?rq=1

Comment: I'd just download it & try it - GHz is not the only measure of how fast a processor is.

Comment: Technically speaking, you *can* upgrade the processor, but it requires the use of a [BGA rework station](http://bit.ly/2i5018i); there are many shops that specialize in this type of work.  That said, the cost of doing this plus the cost of the components outweighs any benefits you may get; you'd be better off getting a replacement logic board or just getting a new(er) MacBook.

Answer (score 7):

You don't. Mobile processors aren't necessarily made to be replaceable - often, they are soldered directly onto the logic board itself. Aside from the obvious voided warranty/extreme risk of damage to the board, you would need to either try the software for download to see if it'll actually run on your machine regardless of specs, or you will need to purchase a new laptop.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, the MacBook Air processor is soldered on and removing it would likely destroy the logic board. If you're looking for a powerful, yet relatively cheap laptop, get a used few-year-old MacBook Pro on eBay for a few hundred dollars (nothing too old, 2011 probably at the latest).

Comment: i tried this and broke my laptop

Answer (score 1):

It’s almost certain you don’t have to strictly honor any GHz requirement or guideline and we can help you optimize your app without needing to swap logic boards or upgrade your Mac.

Let’s get a follow on question if needed with specifics. What software package on what specific version of macOS .

The proper answer is “most Macs have a set processor / memory combination and upgrading them is far more costly than other more effective and more convenient options.”

Think of your Mac like a car engine, most people don’t need to [bore out the cylinders to get more power out of commodity vehicles](https://itstillruns.com/bore-out-engine-cylinder-7500753.html). Some people actually do this and customize their engine, but it’s not worth the training and expense in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can't replace a mac's processor. You can only replace processors in custom-built desktop pc's, when you replace the motherboard either. But let's get into the macbook air discussion, considering you can't replace the CPU...

There is an option to speed up your macbook's processor, you just have to go to about this mac -> and you will directly see your mac's specs. Copy the name of your mac's model (for example: "MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2019)") by selecting it with your mouse pointer and click command + C. Now google this name by clicking Command + V once you clicked the search bar.

Once you click enter, there will appear a webpage from apple support. Open this web page. There will be a little text about your processor. Does this text contain "turbo boost"? Then your mac supports speeding your CPU up using turbo boost! Check out the internet and read about turbo boost. Then speed your CPU up to what's necessary. NOTE: !!!this might affect your battery's life and the temperature your CPU gets to do with!!!

Hopefully this was helpful. Sorry that it's a bit late, but I'll just hope it can still help out other people.

Comment: Wouldn‘t it be easier for everybody if you provide links to tools which allow to enable Turbo Boost?

Comment: > "You can't replace a mac's processor. You can only replace processors in custom-built desktop pc's" - for ThinkPads too.

Answer (score 0):

Logic boards from 2013–2015 Macbook Airs are interchangeable, so if you have one of those models, you could swap your board with one from a newer or faster Macbook Air of the same size.

However, you'd be replacing the bulk of the computer's internals, so this rarely makes sense. You'd be better off selling your current laptop and buying a newer one.

In my case, I had a Macbook Air with my name engraved on the cover, so the swap made economical sense. (Even then, I had a repair shop do the swap for me, but I believe it's a moderately easy thing to do if you're more handy than I am.)

Answer (score -1):

Upgrade processor by purchasing replacement board if you have 1.8 4gig; you buy 2.0 8gig and install.

Answer (score -3):

I remember that in the old days it was possible to fake change the CPU (through the terminal) in order for the OSX to report a faster CPU so that some software could be installed?

Maybe you could look into that? It will not give you a faster machine but might make install the software!